# Best practices when learning a new API

Tags: java, api

When learning/working with a new API, does anyone have any tips for effectively learning it?

I currently make a bunch of `get` requests to understand what I can and cannot retrieve based on the API's responses. From that point I try to map out what is within the API and see what I can build out.

If you guys could share anything what you do that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i do is to read API documentation and search for examples in it. As you get used to read this kind of docs you'll find easier to find exactly what parts of the functionality you need to learn first.

I also use search engines to look for more working examples, and after that I work on creating a minimal use case of the API (for example write a file with commons-io api of apache). For this is a good idea to create a project with multiple JUnit tests with minimal use cases of an API (in the example of commons-io create a file, delete a file, move a file, copy a file, ...).

I must say this is not a science and each API is a new world and may require a slightly differnt approach (As with rest apis you'll need to use some tool like curl or postman to understand how to communicate with them, others will have pre-requirements like have a working installation of a system, and so on).

As everything in coding you'll need to do it by yourself and struggle to solve issues you'll find by yourself (what can take several hours of your free time).

There is no "magic" behind learning something, and coding is in some way like playing a musical instrument, it requires practice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether you are a beginner or you have developed already but will start from scratch..!!

Apis are the code which will allow you to play with the content having certain formats...!!

There are apis based on what operations you want to do are.

1. Get=> In order to fetch something.
2. Post=> In order to save something.
3. Put => to update something.
4. Delete => to delete something.

People also use patch similar to update...!!

You can play around all these by constructing objects and databases...!!

You will require rest services spring restful web service is the ultimate good options..!!

Diving deeper you need to be careful assigning the names you give I mean the meaningful names as you dont know if tomorrow you become famous and need to make your apis sharable ;)

Now some common concerns are like

1. Meaningful Name.
2. Versioning is required like what the old apis are working and now what data your apis give.
3. Can implement swagger its a tool which will allow you to describe the apis like you can write what this api does what type of data it brings etc etc..!!
4. Apis are more or less called an end points means you have that link as a connection between front end and backend So need to keep it secure..!! By authentication.

Above four points are considered to be good practises for writing apis ;)